# Pass initializer list to constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer-list

I have written my own array template class "CArray" and want to pass something like { 1, 2, 3 } to one of its constructors so that I can create an array class instance "CArray a ( {1,2,3}, numElems );

However, I fail to find the proper syntax for the constructor.

```
template <class _T>
class CArray {
    public:
        _T* buffer;
        int length;

    CArray () : buffer (nullptr), length (0) {}

    void Create (int l) {
        buffer = new _T[length = l];
    }
       
    CArray (_T const* values, int numElems) {
        Create (numElems);
        memcpy (buffer, values, numElems * sizeof (_T));
    }
};

CArray<int> a = CArray<int>( {1,2,3}, 3 );
```

This neither works for MSVC 19 latest nor gcc 11.2. How would I have to write my constructor to make this work?

Is there a possibility to omit the "numElems" parameter and get the initializer length (elem count) from the compiler?

Comment: `CArray(std::initializer_list<T> init)` (and you don't need to provide a size, `std::initializer_list` knows its size). See e.g. the `std::vector` constructor, overload (10) [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

Comment: Aside, `_T` is a reserved name (underscore followed by uppercase), and shouldn't be used in code.

Comment: I didn't know about _T being reserved. I've seen it in template class examples (years ago), so I used it. I will change my code. Thx for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the compiler can deduce the size of the brace-init list, if the argument is a reference to an array:

```
template<int numElems> 
CArray (_T const (&values)[numElems]) 
{
   // ...
}
```

and an object is created like this:

```
CArray<int> a = CArray<int>({1,2,3});
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/eobbsr9h7)

Comment: My array class has a dynamically managed buffer, so I don't want a size parameter in the template.

Comment: @Razzupaltuff That's only for the constructor to initialize the internal array. You can still change the size dynamically whenever you want.